# Change the calendar position on mobile layout

Tags: jquery, css, daterangepicker

Change the calendar position on mobile layout,

I used the `daterangepicker-bs3.css` and `daterangepicker.js'`

but the mobile layout is out of my expectation.

## desktop layout, the start date calendar should on the left

[image]

## mobile layout, the start date calendar should on the upper but it turns out to be on the bottom

[image]

## current code

```
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#date-range-picker').daterangepicker(
      {
        locale: {
          applyLabel: "#{escape_javascript t('date_range_picker.apply')}",
          cancelLabel: "#{escape_javascript t('date_range_picker.cancel')}",
          fromLabel: "#{escape_javascript t('date_range_picker.depart_date')}",
          toLabel: "#{escape_javascript t('date_range_picker.return_date')}",
        },
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
        dateLimit: { days: 30 }
      },
      function(start, end, label) {
        console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
      }
    );
  });
```

## html

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="input-prepend input-group">
        <span class="add-on input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </span>
        <input class="form-control" id="date-range-picker" name="departure_at" type="text" value="2015/11/16 - 2015/11/21">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this bootstrap `daterangepicker`? and can you post rendered html for your calendar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, I don't know which version of the daterangepicker are you using. But I tried implementing your code in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ynbwhg8/2/) with the dependencies mentioned in the daterangepicker's [official website](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#usage). It's working the way you want even in the mobile layout.

If you are using older version of daterangepicker, then try passing an attribute "opens: left" while invoking the daterangepicker like this.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#date-range-picker').daterangepicker(
      {
        locale: {
          applyLabel: "#{escape_javascript t('date_range_picker.apply')}",
          cancelLabel: "#{escape_javascript t('date_range_picker.cancel')}",
          fromLabel: "#{escape_javascript t('date_range_picker.depart_date')}",
          toLabel: "#{escape_javascript t('date_range_picker.return_date')}",
        },
          opens: 'left',
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
        dateLimit: { days: 30 }
      },
      function(start, end, label) {
        console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
      }
    );
  });
```

I hope this solves your issue.